# How to parse a string of multiple jsons without separators in python?

Tags: python, arrays, json, amazon-web-services, ndjson

Given a single-lined string of multiple, arbitrary nested json-files without separators, like for example:

```
contents = r'{"payload":{"device":{"serial":213}}}{"payload":{"device":{"serial":123}}}'
```

How can `contents` be parsed into an array of dicts/jsons ? I tried

```
df = pd.read_json(contents, lines=True)
```

But only got a ValueError response:

```
ValueError: Unexpected character found when decoding array value (2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string, then parse each JSON string into a dictionary:

```
import json

contents = r'{"payload":{"device":{"serial":213}}}{"payload":{"device":{"serial":123}}}'

json_strings = contents.replace('}{', '}|{').split('|')
json_dicts = [json.loads(string) for string in json_strings]
```

Output:

```
[{'payload': {'device': {'serial': 213}}}, {'payload': {'device': {'serial': 123}}}]
```