# Reading nested dictionary without using .get

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a file called `sample` (no file format) that looks like this:

```
{
    "schema": "abc",
    "region": "asia",
    "values": {
        "before_values": {
            "id": 123,
            "created_at": "2023-07-28 19:21:39",
            "name": "alex"
        },
        "after_values": {
            "id": 123,
            "created_at": "2024-07-28 19:21:39",
            "name": null
        },
        "file_name": "my_file.1234"
    }
}{
    "schema": "abc",
    "region": "asia",
    "values": {
        "values": {
            "id": 456,
            "created_at": "2023-10-10 17:15:59",
            "name": null
        },
    "file_name": "my_file.1234"
    }
}
```

Note that the file comes in multiple dictionary without delimiter. So I need to read the file like written here (works perfectly!):

```
import json

decoder = json.JSONDecoder()

with open('/path/to/sample', 'r') as content_file: 

    content = content_file.read()

    content_length = len(content)
    decode_index = 0
    raw_data_list = []

    while decode_index < content_length:
        try:
            data, decode_index = decoder.raw_decode(content, decode_index)
            # print("File index:", decode_index)

            print(type(data)) # returns dict

            print(data["schema"]) # works
            print(data["values"]) # works
            print(data["values"]["values"]) # KeyError: 'values'
            # WORKROUND
            raw_data = data.get("values", {})
            # Append raw_data to the list
            raw_data_list.append(raw_data)
    

        except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
            print("JSONDecodeError:", e)
            # Scan forward and keep trying to decode
            decode_index += 1
```

Apparently the workaround to get `data["values"]["values"]` is to add `raw_data = data.get("values", {})`  inside the `try` block. And append to a list then iterate it over such as:

```
for raw_data in raw_data_list:

    raw_data = raw_data.get('values', {})

    print(raw_data)
```

There should be a better way to handle this right? Because retrieving values inside `values` or `before_values` or `after_values` will also have the same issue of KeyError, for eg: accessing `created_at`..

Comment: You can check `if 'values' in raw_data` to find out if the key is present in the (outermost) dict.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74656450/how-to-parse-a-string-of-multiple-jsons-without-separators-in-python) about parsing multiple json objects without separators might be helpful.

Comment: If the first `values` always exists why not `data["values"].get("values", {})`? and if not `data.get("values", {}).get("values", {})`. I don't see why you need to save it in a list just to get the data inside the `while` loop.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25833613/safe-method-to-get-value-of-nested-dictionary

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you want to make a list of a specific "if-available" item (e.g `id`, `created_at`, ..) in each dictionary regardless of how deeper it is. If so and if you're tempted to use [regex](/questions/tagged/regex), you can not only fix your JSON but also build up the expected list :

```
import re, json
from itertools import chain

with (
    open("sample", "r") as inf,
    open("sample.json", "w") as ouf
):
    obj = json.loads("[%s]" % ",".join(
        re.findall(r"({.+?})(?={|\Z)", inf.read().strip(),
                   flags=re.M|re.S)))
    
    json.dump(obj, ouf) # this will make a new/valid JSON file

def fn(o, e):
    def walk(o, e):
        for k, v in o.items():
            if k == e and (val:=o.get(e)):
                yield val
            elif isinstance(v, dict):
                yield from walk(v, e)
    return list(chain.from_iterable([walk(d, e) for d in o]))
```

> Demo : [[*regex101*](https://regex101.com/r/8JN3Fy/1)]

Output :

```
fn(obj, "id")
# [123, 123, 456]

fn(obj, "created_at")
# ['2023-07-28 19:21:39', '2024-07-28 19:21:39', '2023-10-10 17:15:59']
```